# How can I distinguish an axiom from an inferred statement in a Jena RDFS-INF model?

Tags: jena, rdfs, inference

When I create a RDFS_MEM_RDFS_INF model in Jena and read some RDFS-File, a number of statements, that were not explicitly stated in the file are added. E.g. if we have a triple

a p b

and p is a rdfs:subPropertyOf q, than

a q b is

also in the model. A concrete example is the following: if

a skos:related b

is in the file

a skos:semanticRelation b

is also in the model.

Is there any possibility to check whether a statement in the model is  an axiom or an inferred one? There are such methods for OWL Models, but I use the RDFS Model. A trivial solution would be to build two models, one without and one with inference, but I would prefer a less memory consuming solution.

Comment: Jena InfModel has a method `getRawModel()`. This `Model` wont contain the inferred statements, it will contain only the axioms in the file. use a check against that. If you are using the `OntModel` it has got a method `getBaseModel()`.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine! I didn't find that method when I was reading the documentation last week.

Comment: @djthequest You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jena `InfModel` has a method `getRawModel()`. This `Model` wont contain the inferred statements, it will contain only the axioms in the file. use a check against that. If you are using the `OntModel` it has got a method `getBaseModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve [djthequest's answer from a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769713/how-can-i-distinguish-an-axiom-from-an-infered-statement-in-a-jena-rdfs-inf-mode#comment43959618_27769713):

> Jena InfModel has a method getRawModel(). This Model wont contain the
>   inferred statements, it will contain only the axioms in the file. use
>   a check against that. If you are using the OntModel it has got a
>   method getBaseModel().

and [Christian Wartena's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769713/how-can-i-distinguish-an-axiom-from-an-infered-statement-in-a-jena-rdfs-inf-mode#comment43966657_27769713) indicating that this was a solution:

> Thanks. This works fine! I didn't find that method when I was reading
>   the documentation last week.

(I'll remove this answer if djthequest posts one.)